# "No Output" result in C?

Tags: c

I was doing a programming question and one of the sample output is 64197148392731290. My code for that question is correct as it is giving me the right answers for other test cases (output for those test cases are in single digit).

I understand that there will be too many iterations for the test case which has 64197148392731290 as output. So what should I do to get correct answer for that test case too.

Here is the code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main() {
    int test_case;long long int i, j, count, n, k, k1;
    scanf("%d", &test_case);
    while(test_case--) {
        scanf("%lld%lld", &n, &k);
        char a[n];
        count=0;
        k1=k;
        scanf("%s", a);
        while(k1--) {
            strcat(a,a);
        }
        for(i=0;i<(n*k);i++) {
            if(a[i]=='a') {
                for(j=(i+1);j<(n*k);j++) {
                    if(a[j]=='b') {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%lld\n", count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample Input and Output :

Input:

```
3
4 2
abcb
7 1
aayzbaa
12 80123123
abzbabzbazab
```

Output:

```
6
2
64197148392731290
```

My task is to count the number of subsequences "ab" (not necessarily consecutive) in the new string. The first line of the input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.

The first line of each test case contains two integers N and K, denoting the length of the initial string S and the number of repetitions respectively.

The second line contains a string S. Its length is exactly N, and each of its characters is a lowercase English letter.

Comment: What have you done so far? If you have a code, please show it to us so we can help you. Learn [how to ask a good question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You have not told us what the the code is supposed to do!  It may be possible to work that out from the examples; but why should we work that hard - you didn't have to!

Comment: `char a[n];` is not enough. `strcat(a,a);` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Jeff `a[100000000000000]`  can not possibly be secured on the stack.

Comment: Not surprised and VLA that size would have instantly blown the stack!

Comment: Why do you have to tell the program the length of the string - it could figure that out for itself.  I am still unclear from your explanation of the purpose of the code; the second string does not contain "ab" at all.  If the string is repeated, there is surely no need to actually _create_ the string!?  Highly impractical - the answer can surely be calculated arithmetically?

Comment: While those are characters used in the alphabet used in English, it is not the "English" alphabet; it is the "_Latin alphabet_.

Comment: My task is to count the number of subsequences "ab" (not necessarily consecutive) in the new string.

Comment: @Jeff : You have still failed to describe the task unambiguously, there is still no sub-sequence "ab" in the second test.  If the a is separated from the b by other characters, it is not a sequence.  What does the actual question say?

Comment: There are 2 occurrences of the subsequence "ab" in second string: AayzBaa and aAyzBaa.

Comment: @jeff : I see what you mean, butt _subsequence_ is not an accurate description.  They occur in the _order_ a-b but _non-contiguously_. Either way the illustration you have provided in the comment is an improvement and should be put in the question.  The result can be calculated arithmetically by inspection of the entered string alone.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to store input in "int" that wont work coz this number its out of range, change it to "long long int"

Well the previous answer was sure wrong. Thanks for the code.

Sorry don't have time for detailed study but preliminary analysis tells me that maybe the error is because you are trying to store a sting of length 2n in a[n]. It works for smaller values since when you declare

```
char a[n];
       ^
   variable known at runtime
```

it actually allocates a large block so that any value of n within range is possible. For large values `strcat(a,a)` will probably fail.

[image: Not sure image is well visible]

Basically somewhere down the line the string becomes corrupt. Most probably that is because of strcat. I suggest remove strcat, do something else to a similar effect.

Comment: A comment, not an answer;  since the code has been posted after your comment, it is clear than the value is stored in a `long long` in any case.

Comment: What output are you getting for case 3?

Comment: @ParthK No Output.

Comment: Instead of using `strcat(a,a)` try iterating over the same string k times. might help

Comment: With the sizes of n and k in the input, no normal machine can possibly save the string you want it to save. I suggest that instead of making a complete new string you find out the answer for one repetition and somehow devise a method to predict the answer for k repetitions.

Comment: This is still not answering the question;  it is merely debugging his algorithm which is a poor algorithm for a simple problem in any case.

Comment: true that @Clifford